# how to modify luntbuild mail notification template?

Tags: automation, notifications, continuous-integration, luntbuild

We are using luntbuild-1.6.2 for build automation. We would like to add a couple of variables in the email notification sent via luntbuild like subversion location etc.

Is it possible to modify the email template for luntbuild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the [manual](http://luntbuild.javaforge.com/manual/guide/manual.html) once again I was able to locate the files where the template resides.

Simple edit

```
<luntbuild installation path>/templates/email/simple-build.vm
```

file and you can customize the template using a set of [predefined variables](http://luntbuild.javaforge.com/manual/guide/manual.html#adduser).